# How to Install hibernate tools in RAD 9.1

Tags: hibernate, rad

Can anyone please let me know how can I install hibernate tools jar in RAD 9.1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Here is the solution which worked for me]

Use this URL to add the Hibernate tool support into your RAD
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/